# Queue Enqueue function with no if

Tags: c, queue

I have a version of Enque method I was asked to re-write it w/o "if" (or ternary operator).
Couldn't get my head around.
Any help is appreciated.

```
int QueueEnqueue(queue_t *queue, void *data)
{
    s_node_t *new_item = SListCreateNode(data, NULL);

    if (new_item == NULL)
    {
        return (1);
    }

    if (queue->last_item == NULL) /* this one should go away somehow*/
    {
        queue->last_item = queue->first_item      = new_item;
    } else {
        queue->last_item = queue->last_item->next = new_item;
    }

    return(0);
}
```

**[Update] Alternative implementation**

```
int QueueEnqueue(queue_t *queue, void *data)
{
    s_node_t *new_item = SListCreateNode(data, NULL);

    if (new_item == NULL)
    {
        return (1);
    }

    if (queue->last_item == NULL) /* this one should go away somehow */
    {
        queue->first_item      = new_item;
    } else {
        queue->last_item->next = new_item;
    }

    queue->last_item =  = new_item;

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `if (queue->last_item == NULL)` should go away, make sure that `queue->last_item` is never `NULL`. An easiest way to achieve it is to instrument the queue with a dummy head:

```
    typedef struct {
        s_node_t dummy; // Notice it is not a pointer
        s_node_t * last_item;
    } queue_t;

    queue_t * QueueCreate() {
        queue_t * queue = malloc(sizeof(queue_t));
        queue->last_item = &queue->dummy;
        return queue;
    }

    QueueEnqueu(queue_t * queue, void * data) {
        new_item = ....;
        queue->last_item->next = new_item;
        queue->last_item = new_item;
    }
```

Obviously, `QueueDequeue` should return `dummy->next`. I also recommend to use `tail` instead of `last_item`.

Comment: but I still have to initialize `first_item` (i.e. the head) only when queening the first item, this is the actual point of the "if" here, it may be clear if we re-phrase the code as in the updated example